# Нет корректного разрешения для монитора в Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: видеодрайвера, ubuntu

Доброго времени суток!Имеем Ubuntu 12.04.1, видеокарта GeForce 9800 GT, драйвер 304.64. Проблема такая: подключен ЖК монитор Acer AL1716, а драйвер показывает [в настройках CRT монитор](http://files.mail.ru/9F6WUP?t=1) и в доступных разрешениях нет нужного (1280*1024). Монитор подключен через DVI выход видеокарты к VGA входу монитора (с помощью переходника (наверное так подключили за отсутствием DVI кабеля)). Также подключен телевизор Samsung через VGA. Windows для телевизора устанавливает разрешение 1152*864 (я так понимаю это его родное). Среди доступных разрешений в Убунте для обоих мониторов:  320 *240,400* 300,512 *384,640* 480,680 *384,800* 600,1024 *768,1152* 864,1360* 768. [Вот вывод lspci и xrandr](http://ubuntuone.com/5KHdnNkUKukPtWkEzq3GA2) . [Xorg.0.log](http://ubuntuone.com/2ut19impY4Fo9828Ba6Fg3). Как исправить ситуацию? Может можно сделать, чтоб он правильно все определил, или вручную добавить нужное разрешение? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: нужен вывод     xrandr

Comment: Так есть он: "Вот вывод lspci и XRANDR".(http://ubuntuone.com/5KHdnNkUKukPtWkEzq3GA2) Если его кликнуть, откроется скриншот терминала с выводом команд. По ссылке Xorg.0.log сам файл

Comment: да )) не заметил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тогда для первого монитора:

```
# Определение режима для разрешенияcvt 1280 1024# Создание режима с параметрамиxrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync# Добавление режима в DVI-I-0xrandr --addmode DVI-I-0 "1280x1024_60.00"
```

для второго то же самое, только будет VGA-0

Comment: Я не дождался ответа и вечером сам ковырял. Сделал методом тыка ( впрямм смысле). Отключил шнуры на, воткнул только монитор через VGA. Зашел в систему, драйвер определил монитор правильно и дал нужное разрешение. Я сохранил конфигурацию. Подключил телик. там тоже уже было нужное разрешение. В общем сейчас все нормально работает. Может это и не так умно, как вышеописанное, но главное, что сработало. Теперь xrandr выглядит [так](http://ubuntuone.com/00VfBijwxFXTPv705WVHMV)

Comment: Теперь другая проблема. Когда на телевизоре открываю видео с ютюба на весь экран, ничего не могу делать на мониторе, стоит нажать кнопку мыши, как видео на телевизоре выходит из полноэкранного режима. Никто не знает, как с этим быть?

Comment: Отрыть youtube не через браузер?

Comment: Открываю через VLC. При открытом окне на мониторе, в телевизоре [появляется верхняя панель](http://ubuntuone.com/2CkfvCXYzCPCfGNTyeZGoG) . Это можно исправить?

Comment: обычно я сразу ставлю cairo-dock в качестве рабочего стола )) не могу я с юнити. Там всё красиво и более гибко можно настроить.Как это сделать в юнити, не знаю.